# Some reference for categorical logic?

Tags: logic, reference-request, category-theory, categorical-logic

By "categorical logic" I mean category-theoretical models of logic. In particular, I am more interested in models of intuitionistic predicate logic with conjunction, disjunction, implication and quantifiers.

I know about a book of Lambek and Scott and another one by Makkai and Reyes, but these are quite old, especially the second. Does anyone know any newer books/resources on this topic?

For example, I have studied on *propositional* intuitionistic logic (with $\bot,\wedge,\vee$ and $\to$) and the corresponding category-theoretical model is a bicartesian closed category (objects are formulas and arrows are proofs). But what is the case with *predicate* intuitionistic logic? Is there any more recent text analyzing this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what the most recent texts would be, but most of what you are asking about would probably fall into the general category of *topos theory*.

Mac Lane and Moerdijk's **Sheaves in goeometry and logic** (1992) is probably still the best place to start, although if you find it tough going, you could try McLarty's **Elementary Categories, Elementary Toposes** (1992).  If you need a more elementary introduction to category theory, try Awodey's **Category Theory** (2006) or the texts by Barr and Wells (**Category Theory for Computing Science** or **Triples, Toposes, and Theories**), although these aren't as recent.

If you really want to bite off more than you can chew, there is Johnstone's **Sketches of an Elephant** (2002), but you should almost certainly wait a while before trying to tackle that! Somewhat more accessible, but still more of a reference than a textbook is Johnstone's classic **Topos theory** (1974), which is now back in print!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a whole bibliography!

Answer (score 8):

Besides the very good books on topos theory already mentioned, I highly recommend *Categorical Logic* by Andrew Pitts for an introduction to the categorical semantics of type theories (you can find it online [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/papers/catl/catl.pdf). See Section 5 for the treatment of predicate logic).

The more advanced *Categorical Logic and Type Theory* by B. Jacobs, from the series Studies in Logic and the Foundations of Mathematics, is another good reference on the subject.

Comment: I already checked your first recommendation and it fits quite well for what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I recommend Goldblatt's [Topoi: The Categorical Analysis of Logic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Topoi-Categorial-Analysis-Logic-Mathematics/dp/0486450260). (Have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544875/whats-the-best-way-to-teach-oneself-both-category-theory-model-theory) question of mine.)

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53188/decent-texts-on-categorical-logic) MO question is also relevant.

Comment: I checked the book. Unfortunately, it's not what I wanted, because it doesn't study predicate logic, but algebraic and topological models of propositional logic only. The MO question, though, is a good link. Thanks!

Comment: It covers predicate logic in the context of first order languages at least at the start of the 11th chapter, but fair enough. You're welcome :)