# Mathematical structures and signature

Tags: model-theory, meta-math

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure):

> In mathematics, a structure on a set, or more generally a type,
> consists of additional mathematical objects that in some manner attach
> (or relate) to the set, making it easier to visualize or work with, or
> endowing the collection with meaning or significance.
>
> A partial list of possible structures are measures, algebraic
> structures (groups, fields, etc.), topologies, metric structures
> (geometries), orders, equivalence relations, differential structures,
> and categories.

From [Planetmath](https://planetmath.org/structure):

> Let $\tau$ be a signature. A $\tau$-structure $\mathcal{A}$
> comprises of a set $A$, called the universe
> (or underlying set or domain) of
> $\mathcal{A}$, and an interpretation of the symbols of $\tau$
> as follows:
>
> - for each constant symbol $c\in\tau$, an element
>   $c^A\in A$;
> - for each $n$-ary function symbol $f\in\tau$, a
>   function (or operation) $f^A:A^n\rightarrow A$;
> - for each $n$-ary
>   relation symbol $R\in\tau$, a $n$-ary relation $R^A$ on $A$.

I was wondering

1. Can structures defined as a set of subsets, such as
   $\sigma$-algebra, topology, be described as signature-structures?
2. Can structures defined as a mapping from the set to another set,
   such as metric, measure, norm, inner product, be described as
   signature-structures?
3. Are signature-structures special kinds of structures defined only by operations and/or relations?
4. In the Wikipedia quote "a structure on a set, or more generally a type", does it mean a structure is also called  a type, or the underlying set is a type?
5. Fundamentally, is "mathematical structure" a concept of model theory, category
   theory, or some other theory?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: By interpreting everything in a formal set theory, the absurdly open-ended definition of Wikipedia can be accommodated.

Comment: Thanks, @AndréNicolas! Why is Wiki absurdly open ended? Don't you think sigma algebras, topologies, metric, inner product, norm are structures?

Comment: As I read the "definition," I cannot think of anything that would **not** qualify.  As to your specific questions, one can force (for example) a general vector space to be a first-order structure by having a two predicate symbols $V$, $S$ ($x$ is a vector, $x$ is a scalar). One can operate similarly with other notions such as inner products, even measures. So far this has not proved profitable.

Comment: Thanks, @AndréNicolas! What does the order of structure mean, like first-order structure, second-order structure, zero-order structure?

Comment: First order language: variables range over objects. Second-order language: There are variables of two types, the first ranging over objects, the second ranging over sets of objects. So for example Peano's axiomatization of arithmetic was second-order, every non-empty **subset** has a smallest element. The first-order version has infinitely many instances of the induction axiom, one for every formula $F(x)$. The second-order version has up to isomorphism one model, the first-order version has many models.

Comment: Thanks! Is there zero-order thing?

Comment: The term is as far as I know not used. One could maybe apply it to propositional logic.

Answer (score 5):

1. Sure. For a good explanation, see the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97856/topological-spaces-as-model-theoretic-structures-definitions) by Brian M. Scott.
2. If the sets in question are $X$ and $Y$, these mappings are just subsets of $P(X \times Y)$. In this way, one can view these spaces as model-theoretic structures as in Brian's explanation for $(1)$. More generally, check out the introduction in the paper [model theory for metric structures](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~henson/cfo/mtfms.pdf) to see how these sorts of structures are studied.
3. In Model Theory, structures arise from theories in a given signature. I am not sure if there is a notion of a structure existing independently from a signature.
4. A type is something of a generalization of a structure. I really don't know anything about types, so I'm hoping somebody here can fill in this part of my answer.
5. The term "mathematical structure" has a specific meaning in model theory. To my knowledge, that is not the case in category theory. Generally speaking, it is a philosophical idea that would be hard to pin down to any specific branch of math.