# Example of topological space up to ''first-order facts''

Tags: general-topology, first-order-logic

This question is motivated by the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4167567/can-we-express-the-theory-of-a-single-topology-as-a-multi-sorted-theory).

I am not familiar with the formalism the OP uses but, in short, it is about whether it is possible to formulate a first-order theory for a single topology or not.
One of the paragraphs of the answer provided by Noah Schweber says the following:

> *This is the sense in which topology is not first-order: any attempt to "first-orderize" topology will result in things which look like topological spaces "up to first-order facts" but are not in fact topological spaces.*

I am asking for examples of those things which look like topological spaces up to first-order facts.
I would like to know if such things, not only topological spaces but objects which look like common objects we use in maths up to first-order (or higher) facts have ever been used or studied.

PS: There is a tag called ''generalized topology''. I have looked for the definition on Google and it seems it is not related to this, but who knows...

Comment: I have found the first example of such things: Real closed fields. According to Wiki's definition, a _real closed field_ is a field which has the same first-order properties as the field of real numbers. Examples of that are the fields of algebraic real numbers and of the hyperreal numbers.