# What is the formal definition of nonfirstorderizable?

Tags: definition, first-order-logic

In philosophy and mathematics, people talk of something being nonfirstorderizable. But in all the texts I have seen, there is no formal definition of that concept. So, is there a formal definition of nonfirstorderizable somewhere?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46656/why-is-topology-nonfirstorderizable The user @CarlMummert gives an awesome answer here

Comment: Have you checked the Wikipedia article? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonfirstorderizability